# How to check if any alert is present on Selenium test with function subTest

Tags: python-3.x, testing, selenium-webdriver

Q: What i need?
A: I need to check ANY alert is present, if user click on `<a href="#">` to remove row on table. I cant use "Try-except" feature for Selenium test. I need something like:

```
with self.subTest('Testing alert in transaction {}'.format(value['link'])):
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//table/tbody/tr[1]/td[last()]/a/i[@class="fa fa-remove"]').click()
    self.assertTrue(EC.alert_is_present(), 'Alert is present')
```

> EC.alert_is_present()

What operator i can use to check alerts?

Comment: Why you *cant use "Try-except" feature for Selenium test*?

Comment: @Andersson, because i don't know, how to return result "passed", when the alert not presented. I trying to create "export Test Results" in intellij, where devs can see error logs
P.S. Sorry for my eng

Comment: You can simply define `result = False` and then `try: ... result = True`,  and finally `assertTrue(result, 'Alert is present')`

Comment: @Andersson, yeah, i think, it's right. Thanks :)